# Cannot find node ' '. How to add downloaded Info document file so that info command worked?

Tags: info

`info make` opened same as `man make`. I've downloaded `make.info.tar.gz` file from https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/, then:

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/make.info.tar.gz /usr/share/info/

sudo install-info /usr/share/info/make.info.tar.gz /usr/share/info/dir
```

I got info (no pun intended) from https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/texinfo.html#Installing-an-Info-File

Now there is a new entry when I do `info`:

> - Make: (make).                 Remake files automatically.

But when I select it I get `Cannot find node ''`. `info make` still displays man page, not Info document page. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you downloaded is an archive, you need to extract its contents:

```
sudo tar -C /usr/share/info -xof make.info.tar.gz &&
  sudo install-info /usr/share/info/make.info /usr/share/info/dir
```

Renaming it as you did happens to work because there’s a single file in the archive, and the `tar` header ends up mostly ignored by `info`; but `zless /usr/share/info/make.info.gz` should show you noise at the top of the page.

Comment: Indeed `zless` had shown `sed.info.gz` and mine differently. I still wonder why gnu.org does post with tar for one file archive. As the rest in `/usr/share/info/` are `.gz` I think I'm repacking after extracting.

Comment: The tarball is generated by [`gendocs.sh`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/plain/build-aux/gendocs.sh); building info docs can result in multiple files, so the info output is designed around that.

Answer (score 0):

I've noted other files in `/usr/share/info/` are named e.g. `sed.info.gz`. Renaming `make.info.tar.gz` to `make.info.gz` and rerunning below solved the problem

```
sudo install-info /usr/share/info/make.info.gz /usr/share/info/dir
```

I wonder why gnu.org has so named files for download. "Info document (268K bytes gzipped tar file)." Maybe on another systems files are named `tar.gz`? I'm on Linux Mint 21 based.